# Android Studio: PHP mysql variable isnt being passed in RegisterAPI when adding 2 variables

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to use a Form and PHP to pass a variable into the PHP file to POST into MySQL. I was able to get all of the variables but a calculated one. I just can't get to work.  I can make the toast show the calculated number, but not carry it forward.

In MainActivity: I am trying to calculate `emptyMilage` - `loadedMilage`.

I created a private textview or string, I have tried almost everything, and know is just something I can't grasp yet.

I have attached the MainActivity and RegisterAPI class I am using along with the SQL import.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaring views
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText trucksID;
    private EditText tripReportNumber;
    private EditText enteredDate;
    private EditText emptyMilage;
    private EditText loadedMilage;

    private Button buttonRegister;
    private String estTotal;
    private TextView estMilage;

    //This is our root url
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://rooturl_for_php/php/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        trucksID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trucksID);
        tripReportNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripReportNumber);
        enteredDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredDate);
        emptyMilage= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emptyMilage);
        loadedMilage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loadedMilage);
        estMilage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estMilage);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        //Adding listener to button
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }




    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
// Just took out Menu options, since that is working well //

    private void insertUser(){
        //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
        //Creating a RestAdapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        RegisterAPI api = adapter.create(RegisterAPI.class);

        //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
        api.insertUser(

                //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
                trucksID.getText().toString(),
                tripReportNumber.getText().toString(),
                enteredDate.getText().toString(),
                emptyMilage.getText().toString(),
                loadedMilage.getText().toString(),
                //can take this out below
                estMilage.getText().toString(),

                //Creating an anonymous callback
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                        //Creating a bufferedreader object
                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        //An string to store output from the server
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            //Initializing buffered reader
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                            //Reading the output in the string
                            output = reader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //Displaying the output as a toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //Overriding onclick method
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling insertUser on button click
        insertUser();
        int value1=Integer.parseInt(emptyMilage.getText().toString());
        int value2=Integer.parseInt(loadedMilage.getText().toString());

        int estMilage=value2-value1;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Estimated Milage:"+String.valueOf(estMilage), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the RegisterAPI I created

```
public interface RegisterAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/insert.php")
    public void insertUser(
            @Field("trucksID") String trucksID,
            @Field("tripReportNumber") String tripReportNumber,
            @Field("enteredDate") String enteredDate,
            @Field("emptyMilage") String emptyMilage,
            @Field("loadedMilage") String loadedMilage,
            @Field("estTotal") String estTotal,
            Callback<Response> callback);
}
```

And here is the final, after I use a $conn php file insert.php

```
<?php
//checking if the script received a post request or not 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //Getting post data 
        $trucksID = $_POST['trucksID'];
        $tripReportNumber = $_POST['tripReportNumber'];
        $enteredDate = $_POST['enteredDate'];
        $emptyMilage = $_POST['emptyMilage'];
        $loadedMilage = $_POST['loadedMilage'];
        $estTotal = $_POST['estTotal'];

        //checking if the received values are blank
        if($trucksID == '' || $tripReportNumber == '' || $emptyMilage == '' || $loadedMilage == '' ){
            //giving a message to fill all values if the values are blank
            echo 'Please fill all values';
        }else{
            //If the values are not blank
            //Connecting to our database by calling dbConnect script 
            require_once('dbConnect.php');

            //Creating an SQL Query to insert into database 
            //Here you may need to change the drivers_report because it is the table I created
            //if you have a different table write your table's name

            //This query is to check whether the Trip Report is already registered or not 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM drivers_report WHERE trucksID='$trucksID'";

            //If variable check has some value from mysqli fetch array 
            //That means username or email already exist 
            $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

            //Checking check has some values or not 
            if(isset($check)){
                //If check has some value that means username already exist 
                echo 'Trip Report already exists';
            }else{              
                //If username is not already exist 
                //Creating insert query 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO drivers_report (trucksID,tripReportNumber,enteredDate,emptyMilage,loadedMilage,estTotal) VALUES('$trucksID','$tripReportNumber','$enteredDate','$emptyMilage','$loadedMilage','$estTotal')";

                //Trying to insert the values to db 
                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                    //If inserted successfully 
                    echo 'Trip Report Submitted!';
                }else{
                    //In case any error occured 
                    echo 'oops! Please try again!';
                }
            }
            //Closing the database connection 
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
}else{
echo 'error';
}
```

The variable can change but has to populate the estTotal in the php file.
Thank you for any help, I have spent about a week trying to change the code about 50 times to work and I am still stuck.

Also attached the `Activity_Main.xml` for screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Truck ID:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trucksID"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Trip Report Number:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tripReportNumber"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Trip Date:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enteredDate"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="MM/DD/YY" />



    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Empty Milage:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emptyMilage"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Loaded Milage:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loadedMilage"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:text="Submit Trip Report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/estMilage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

### Re-Adding in full MainActivity file:

```
package com.johncbell.atrixtrucking;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

//Class for our main activity with OnClickListener
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaring views
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText trucksID;
    private EditText tripReportNumber;
    private EditText enteredDate;
    private EditText emptyMilage;
    private EditText loadedMilage;

    private Button buttonRegister;
    private String estTotal;
    private TextView estMilage;

    //This is our root url
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://URLOFPHPFILE/php/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        trucksID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trucksID);
        tripReportNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripReportNumber);
        enteredDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredDate);
        emptyMilage= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emptyMilage);
        loadedMilage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loadedMilage);
        estMilage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estMilage);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        //Adding listener to button
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }




    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.openWebsite:
                Intent website = new Intent(this,ourWebsite.class);
                this.startActivity(website);
                return true;

            case R.id.goto2:
                Intent activity2 = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
                this.startActivity(activity2);
                return true;

            case R.id.about_us:
                Intent about = new Intent(this,aboutUs.class);
                this.startActivity(about);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void insertUser(){
        //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
        //Creating a RestAdapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        RegisterAPI api = adapter.create(RegisterAPI.class);

        //Defining the method insertuser of our interface

        int value1=Integer.parseInt(emptyMilage.getText().toString());
        int value2=Integer.parseInt(loadedMilage.getText().toString());
        int estMilage=value2-value1;

        api.insertUser(

                api.insertUser(
                        //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
                        trucksID.getText().toString(),
                        tripReportNumber.getText().toString(),
                        enteredDate.getText().toString(),
                        emptyMilage.getText().toString(),
                        loadedMilage.getText().toString(),
                        //can take this out below
                        Integer.toString(estMilage),


                //Creating an anonymous callback
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                        //Creating a bufferedreader object
                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        //An string to store output from the server
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            //Initializing buffered reader
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                            //Reading the output in the string
                            output = reader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //Displaying the output as a toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                );
    }

    //Overriding onclick method
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling insertUser on button click
        insertUser();

    }
}
```

Comment: So is `estMilage` supposed to come from the `EditText` or from the operation?

Comment: it is supported to be the Final result i can pass to the PHP file, i only want it shown on the Toast message, do not need it on screen.

Comment: Is there a reason why your operation is not inside the `insertUser()` method?

Comment: besides maybe not knowing, how to move the logic in there. Sorry first Project file. Still learning

Comment: It's a bit much for the comments so I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `api.insertUser(`, try:

```
int value1=Integer.parseInt(emptyMilage.getText().toString());
int value2=Integer.parseInt(loadedMilage.getText().toString());
int estMilage=value2-value1;
```

then `api.insertUser(` should be:

```
 api.insertUser(
                //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
                trucksID.getText().toString(),
                tripReportNumber.getText().toString(),
                enteredDate.getText().toString(),
                emptyMilage.getText().toString(),
                loadedMilage.getText().toString(),
                //can take this out below
                Integer.toString(estMilage),
```

Comment: Two part question: 1) I added in the Line, but not estMilage.setText  the setText is showing "cant resolve method"

Comment: And should i take out, the string at the bottom for the Toast. To not duplice it

Comment: insertUser();
        int value1=Integer.parseInt(emptyMilage.getText().toString());
        int value2=Integer.parseInt(loadedMilage.getText().toString());

        int estMilage=value2-value1;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Estimated Milage:"+String.valueOf(estMilage), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Yeah remove that from the `onClick`. Leave `insertUser()` as the only thing in `onClick`. I also need to revise my answer. Give me one second.

Comment: When i added in 5 lines, where you advised, not getting "setText"  as Error:(118, 17) error: '.class' expected and Error:(154, 18) error: ';' expected in Log

Comment: Okay for now, remove `estMilage.getText().toString()` from `api.insertUser` & replace it with `Integer.toString(estMilage)`. This will not display `estMilage` but it'll pass the right value. Let me know if this works. Also remove `estMilage.setText(Integer.toString(estMilage));`

Comment: When its under "loadedMilage.gettext().toString(); or above in teh spi.insertUser the "estMilage.setText> still shows red.  with cant resolve (setText(java.lang.String)

Comment: Last part is stuck:
        ); <--- Error:(158, 10) error: ')' expected 
    }

    //Overriding onclick method

Comment: You added `api.insertUser(` twice. You just need to replace your `api.insertUser(` with the one I gave you.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much.  I spend hours and hours banging my head.  5Stars for that.,

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.